# facebook graph page/picture edge returning questionmark

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So this is a little bit odd, I have a website that trawls facebook looking at specific pages and requesting data from them.

As part of this I request the picture object of the page: http://graph.facebook.com/285361880228/picture

This returns a question mark instead of the page profile picture.

Other links to pages seem to work without a problem.
http://graph.facebook.com/1485760851674064/picture

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

I am currently using version 2.3 of the API.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the page setup, as according to the facebook documentation,I should be able to read this.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/picture/

Comment: It seems to work when the request is made using a user access token … might be that this page is access restricted in some way (by age, location, …), or has targetting enabled. Or it might be privacy settings of the image itself – if you go to [the single view](https://www.facebook.com/bbcafrica/photos/a.468385385228.278318.285361880228/10150860797180229/?type=3&theater) of that picture on Facebook, you’ll see that it is shared with a custom audience.

Comment: I had a feeling it may be something like this, I will get the owner of the page to check their page settings and image settings. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the facebook page has not been published. Try publishing the page and access the image using same link. It will work.